# Norm equality implies parallesim

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be some real invertible matrix, and let $u$ and $v$ be two vectors. It is known that
$$
||u ||^2=||Av ||^2
$$ 
and
$$
||v ||^2=||A^{-1}u ||^2
$$

Does these imply that $u=Av$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take any orthogonal matrix $A$ and any two vectors $u,v$ of norm 1 which do not satisfy $u=Av$.

Comment: Of course...
Thanks!